Are SO users legally entitled to any benefits from the SE-OpenAI deal?
I am not a lawyer, or at least not formally and not in the US, but I've read the recent post:
Stack Overflow and OpenAI Partner to Strengthen the World’s Most Popular Large Language Models
I realize, of course, that our posts to the SE network are publicly available, and also licensed to SE for use; but - does the license we grant SE mean that they can profit  exclusively from facilitating/enhancing access to that content? Do we - individually or collectively - have no claim to (part of) such proceeds? Also, can SE inc. be considered to have non-monetary obligations vis-a-vis the users due to this deal?

SE has already been profiting from users' content - through ad revenue. There have also been other collaborations for profit, like the Facebook one, or sponsored tags, or the Collectives. Users have never been given any of the revenue from those. To the best of my knowledge, no big claims have been made either. This deal does not seen fundamentally different to how the users' content has been used for profit historically.

SE can do whatever they want. They can grab the money, payback (with interest) their investors, transfer the last money to any creditors and turn-off the light. There are no SO users in this equation, never have been. Don't pretend that should change now.

@rene: I'm not pretending, I'm asking.

The important part to watch out for is whether the new partnership sticks to the attribution requirements. Thats something that historically OpenAI has not done, and I’m curious to see if they will.  The IP-laundering is what concerns me, as otherwise we’ve already given SE a irrevocable license to use our material — just with attribution.

Well, if we go by the license as long as the content shared by the company has proper attribution they can do whatever they want with it. To put it in simple terms no we aren't legally entitled to any benefits.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: They can "do whatever they want" with it, ok, but - that's not the same thing. I did not ask whether we can prevent them from cooperating with OpenAI.

@einpoklum the license allows commercial use and it doesn't necessitate any kind of profit sharing etc. with the original author. So no we aren't legally entitled to any benefits from the deal, whether Stack Overflow chooses to do so is another story.

@einpoklum the "do whatever they want" is tied to "as long as the content shared by the company has proper attribution" and literally just describes the CC by-SA license. It allows you to do whatever you want with the work as long as the license terms are upheld. In short, the license terms require attribution and redistribute must use include copyright + the same license. That's it - there is nothing that the original author has to receive anything from their redistributed (or even potentially changed) work. So SE has no legal obligations to share earnings.

@GeorgeStocker and VLAZ: so is the attribution required to be "<specific URL to SO question/answer>" or "user X on SO" or merely "StackOverflow.com"?

@smci there are various questions about how to give attribution on Meta. Here's one of them. You can also look at the license itself for the exact terms.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: thanks but having read those, the "should" phrasing is too hand-wavy; my reaction is "Does attribution under SO's licensing a) require specific URL and SO username of author to be cited? b) will SO actually enforce that on OpenAI and all other users? (what is the enforcement mechanism and penalty if they don't?)" I'm not seeing any hard yes from SO.

@smci Stack Overflow's (i.e., the company's) statement on attribution requirements for partnerships is here.

@smci regarding point "a" the license would require the creator / author's name and a URL to the post given they are present / readily available. About point "b" technically the only responsibility SO has is to provide this proper attribution when they share the content with OpenAI, following the license's terms is then OpenAI's responsibility. Stack Overflow cannot use the CC BY-SA license to enforce that since they don't actually own the copyright. If the deal includes those as part of its terms though then Stack Overflow could potentially enforce OpenAI to do that.

In other terms the enforcement mechanism depends on the deal Stack Overflow made with OpenAI whose terms we as normal users of the site don't really know.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: I wonder if we don't have even the right to know the terms of their deal :-(

@einpoklum What, exactly, is Stack Overflow's agreement with OpenAI?


Are SO users legally entitled to any benefits from the SE-OpenAI deal?

No, they aren't.

does the license we grant SE mean that they can profit exclusively from facilitating/enhancing access to that content?

I don't know where that "exclusively" is coming from, but the license means they can profit from the content. That's what they do: profit from the content we provide. It's the basic game-plan.
But it's certainly not exclusive. You can also use the content here (provided by you or otherwise), for profit. You should follow the terms of the license. Seek lawyer advice if unsure.

The content is already on the Internet, probably archived. We have to move on...

This doesn't answer the question and is very poorly worded.

Not probably archived. it is archived, by design, every 3 months, knowledge available for everyone: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922

But archiving has nothing to do with generating new content purely based on existing content. Archiving does not create nwe content or alter existing content, it just prevents content from being lost.
